# MongoDB error: can't call something /127.0.0.1:27017/admin

Tags: android, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongodb through an android application, Mongodb is running in local

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("dbname");
```

I am getting the error as can't call something: /127.0.0.1:27017/admin
mongodb is running at the back.

I wanted to know why admin?? There is no collection like admin in my DB.

When I connect using the command line, it works, and I am able to insert and query data.

I don't know what is going wrong.  Nothing has been mentioned in the examples I have browsed so far about any kind of configuration that needs to be done.

Kindly help!!

Comment: You're running that code on Android? Where's your MongoDB server? You'd normally need to use the IP address of the database server and not just accept the defaults which would normally be the loopback adapter (127.0.0.1).

Comment: @pcurry - i am running mongodb locally..i gave the following command .."C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" in command prompt and got something like this...
Wed Feb 05 00:52:30.918 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on 
port 27017
Wed Feb 05 00:52:30.918 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on po
rt 28017
so it tells that mongodb is listening to port 27017 ...so that means in code i am suppose to use port 27017 and host as "localhost"...correct me if i am wrong..i tried above still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running your application in Android, I would implicitly assume your MongoDB server must be running somewhere else on a different ip address that is not 127.0.0.1. By default, in absence of hostname / ip address, MongoClient tries to connect to localhost loopback address of 127.0.0.1 on port 27017 (default port until something else is specified), and fails because there is MongoDB server instance running on the localhost. I would suggest following:

1. Look into details of where your server is located and get hostname / port details for it.
2. Look into MongoDB Java API further and some sample apps http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/ on how to access MongoDB that is running on a different server.

Comment: the link u referred tells to connect to mongoclient using new command..but nothing is mentioned to run the mongodb in command prompt before executing the application..and if i run locally using the command..it gives the below result 
[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Wed Feb 05 00:52:30.918 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on po
rt 28017

Comment: also i tried hosting mongodb in heroku ...got a lengthy url something like this  "<somenumber>.mongolab.com:61198/heroku_app<number>" ..when i use "mongo <somenumber>.mongolab.com:61198/heroku_app<number> -u username -p password" in command prompt i am able to connect to database and insert documents in it...how am i suppose to use this url in android application using mongoclient() api.. giving the same url in new mongoclient() method ??? thanks in advance !!

Comment: when i give that url..its showing me exception as invalid int

Answer (score 0):

As commented on your question as your client is on a different platform to the server you need to specify the full host connection rather than use the default.

That said:

**DO NOT DO THAT!**

You most certainly do not want your MongoDB instance accessible over the internet in this way.  What you want is a web service to proxy your requests and pass them on to MongoDB. You can do that yourself or look into something that might be listed here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

Exposing your database to the internet is never a good idea for various reasons but the two most prominent being security and firewall rules that are not going to allow traffic over certain ports. HTTP is going to be available just about everywhere and is the most useful means of communication for a mobile app.

Comment: so you mean to say i should use REST api written in node.js to access the mongodb ?? well i tried that too locally..its working fine..but thought of connecting mongodb directly from android app and insert,query data using mongodb api ?? any disadvantages of not using webservices to connect to mongodb instead of connecting directly ??

Comment: The link has a list of several REST implementations that exist already. You may use these or your own service points that you write. I edited my response with my reasoning for saying this, and it is considered best practice to do things this way. You most certainly want some sort of server side component and processing for  any useful mobile app using remote data, and beyond just simple CRUD operations.

Comment: ok Neil will check the APIs thank you for your suggestions :)